# PowerBI - DAX EARLIER() Function syntax error

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax

I have the below function that works in Excel.

```
CALCULATE(
    MIN('Table1'[T1_Column]),
    FILTER(
        ALL('Table1'),
        AND(RELATED(Table2[T2_Column]) = EARLIER(Table2[T2_Column]), RELATED('Table3'[T3_Column]) = "string")
    )
)
```

However, when I try to copy and paste the same equation into PowerBI, I get a syntax error on Table2[T2_Column] in the EARLIER function. As well as the intellisense doesn't populate. What's wrong with my calculation?

Comment: I'm a little surprised, as I wouldn't have thought that construction would work in Power Pivot either. Can you clarify with a very small mock dataset together with the result you get using your formula?

Comment: Did you try this code in measure or in CalculatedColumn? Did you check your model relationship (you use RELATED which is based on relationship).